# Erro ao inserir Slider dentro de View - Swift

Tags: swift, view, slider

Estou com um problema relacionado ao Slider do Swift quando tento colocar ele dentro de uma View

Meu projeto tem a seguinte estrutura

- View (principal)

  - View (utilizada para agrupamento)

    - ScrollView

      - View (Objetos)

Se eu coloco o Slider dentro da View Principal, View de Agrupamento e ScrollView ele corresponde com seu funcionamento, se eu coloco ele dentro da View de Objetos que é a última ele para de funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Remova a View de agrupamento, deixe apenas a View principal e coloque os objetos lá dentro.